# mysql error msg reading table data (Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in)

Tags: php, mysql

ive this table which is updated and re-ranked every midnight , 
after few days i start getting this msg

```
   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
```

in last page of pagination to fix it i used to trunk the table and run my code again then its work fine , here is my mysql statement case the issue

```
   mysql_free_result($result);


   $i = 0;
    $total_amount = count($tweeps);

    foreach  ($tweeps as $tweep) {
            $i++;
            if ($total_amount == $i) {

    $class = 'divrow divrowlast';
            } else {
              $class = 'divrow';
            }
```

need to tips to do permanent fix

Comment: This has little to do with `mysql`. Further, you should not be using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: ill need to re-factor all my code to replace mysql_  but mean while im looking for fix  for my issue

Comment: Can you show where `$tweeps` is defined?

Comment: There is nothing functionally wrong with this code other than a closing bracket. Please provide more context.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed - It would be well worth it to refactor your code, especially going forward. The mysql_* functions are considered deprecated as of PHP 5.5

Comment: here is my code http://codepad.org/od9vsX5j

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what `$tweeps` contains its hard to help. You are however missing a closing bracket. For practice you should check if `$tweeps` is in fact an array though. My assumption is that `$tweeps` isn't an array.

```
if (is_array($tweeps)) {
    foreach ($tweeps as $tweep) {
        $i++;
        if ($total_amount == $i) {
            $class = 'divrow divrowlast';
        } else {
            $class = 'divrow';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: Yeah, looking at the code, it appears that `$tweeps` can be undefined.

Comment: If you do a `print_r($tweeps);` right before `mysql_free_result($result);` what do you get?

Comment: i got data from $tweeps , the problems is here https://www.sudanesetweeps.com/  check last page then gor backward til page 293 , where the data start appear ,

Comment: Try `if (is_array($tweeps) && !empty($tweeps)) {}` around your foreach loop.

Comment: nothing happened , the same things  ,  one more thing in table ive 2915 row  and my pagination keep telling ist 3014